# Could not load type for role provider

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership

I'm using custom role and membership providers. Both are in namespace `MyDomain.Infrastructure.Security`

`MyCustomMembershipProvider` has filename: MyCustomMembershipProvider.cs 
`MyCustomMembershipRoleProvider` has filename: MyCustomMembershipRoleProvider.cs

Inside webconfig I have configured sections to use my cystom providers like:

```
<membership defaultProvider="MyCustomMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="MyCustomMembershipProvider"
         type="MyDomain.Infrastructure.Security"
         enablePasswordRetrieval="false"... />
  </providers>
```

```
<roleManager enabled="true"
             defaultProvider="MyDomain.Infrastructure.Security">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add applicationName="/" name="MyCustomMembershipRoleProvider"
             type="MyDomain.Infrastructure.Security" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
```

Even it's the same namespace on build I'm getting error on role provider and not for membership provider

Error message is:

> *Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'MyDomain.Infrastructure.Security'.*

Line 54:

```
<add applicationName="/" name="MyCustomMembershipRoleProvider"
     type="MyDomain.Infrastructure.Security" />
```

Update:
As answer below suggests I added following

```
<add applicationName="/" name="MyDomain.Infrastructure.Security.MyCustomMembershipRoleProvider, MyDomain.Infrastructure.Security" type="MyDomain.Infrastructure.Security" />
```

but error message remains the same.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: keep name as previous but need to change the `type`, what you done is incorrect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try with

```
type="MyDomain.Infrastructure.Security.MyCustomMembershipRoleProvider, MyDomain.Infrastructure.Security"
```

after `,` give the assembly name, here i assume it is `MyDomain.Infrastructure.Security`

Answer (score 1):

If you have your role provider class in the App_Code folder, then you need to change the "Build Action" property for the class file to "compile".

Answer (score 0):

I have resovled this problem. There was difference in framework, My mvc project was in .net framework 4.0 and Provider library project solution was in .net framework 4.5. I resolved this by changing my custom provider solution's .net framework to 4.0.